# JQuery toggle change input value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Excuse me,I want to toggle change php echo input value,

but is error , How can I do? please help me , thanks!

php code

```
<?php
$date = isset($_GET['date']) ? $_GET['date'] : date('Y-m-d');
$prev_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date .' -1 week'));

$next_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date .' +1 week'));
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date .'+1 day'));
    echo $date;
    for ($j=1; $j<=5 ; $j++) {
        echo "<input type='button' value='X' class='change'>";
    }
    echo '<br>';

}
?>
```

javascritp code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('.change').toggle(function(){
      $(this).val('O');},
      function(){
      $(this).val('X');}
 );
});
```

Comment: when user click on any X, it value should become 0, and if user click on any 0, it value should become 1..right?

Comment: not getting what you want exactly

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/ , `toggle-event` depreciated in `1.8` and removed in `1.9`

Comment: What you want? Please explain more.

Comment: @DharaParmar  yes!  when user click on any X, it value should become 0, and if user click on any 0, it value should become X

Comment: @Mohammad  Hello, I just want to clikc on any X ,it value change O , and clcick on any O , it value change X

Comment: @Bruce See https://jsfiddle.net/tag65uh3/ . Is it your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below script:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.change').click(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == 'X')
            $(this).val('O');
        else if ($(this).val() == 'O')
            $(this).val('X');
    });
});
```